# Cluster View (green bubble) showing above Callout View in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am programmatically selecting Annotation View to open Callout View but Cluster View (green bubble) is showing above Callout View. Is there any way to send back the green bubble and display the full Callout View in MapKit?

[image]

Comment: can you show us your code?